# Django request.GET.get() returns None every two times

Tags: python, django, ajax, request

I'm trying to use some ajax request to echange between django views and the templates but i'm experiencing a strange behavior with the request.GET.
Django sends an error saying that the data in parameter of the `json.loads(data)` shouldn't be *NoneType* as the result of `request.GET.get('selects')` seems to be *None*; but if I try to debug this code, it seems that `request.GET.get('selects')` returns *None* every two times.
When requesting  `request.GET.get('selects')` in the console, I get:
 
None the first time 
and '[{"pk":"57226796-0960-428a-88aa-ba4120ad34b4"}]' the second time,
 
then None again 
then '[{"pk":"57226796-0960-428a-88aa-ba4120ad34b4"}]' at the third attempt.
 
every odd attempt return None....
what do I wrong ?

**views.py**

```
class AjaxRenameView(View):

    def get(self,request):
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        selects=request.GET.get('selects', None)
        selects=json.loads(selects)
        pks = [ pk['pk'] for pk in selects]
        if len(pks)==1:
            folder=Folder.objects.filter(pk=pks[0])
            spotler=Spotler.objects.filter(pk=pks[0])
            if folder:
                form=FolderRenameForm(instance=folder)
                title=_('rename folder')
            elif spotler :
                form=SpotlerRenameForm(instance=folder)
                title=_('rename project')

            context={'form':form,'title':title,'submit':_('rename'),'has_error':False}
            html_form = render_to_string('includes/modal_form.html',
                context,
                request=request,
            )
            return JsonResponse({'html_form': html_form})

        return JsonResponse({'has_error':True, 'message':_('an error has occured while renaming')}, safe=False)

    def post(self,request):
        pass
```

**folder.js**

```
  //...
  function ajaxAction(selects,url,next){
    // when clicked on item of menu (rename, share, move...)
    $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      data:{'selects':JSON.stringify(selects),'next':next},
      url: url,
      dataType:"json",
      beforeSend: function () {
        $("#Modal .modal-content").empty();
      },
      success: function (data) {
        $("#Modal .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
      }
    });//ajax
  }//function ajaxAction
//...
```

**console**

```
(Pdb) request.GET.dict()
{'selects': '[{"pk":"57226796-0960-428a-88aa-ba4120ad34b4"}]', 'next': '/fr/wf/myfiles/'}
(Pdb) request.GET.get('selects')
(Pdb) request.GET.get('selects')
'[{"pk":"57226796-0960-428a-88aa-ba4120ad34b4"}]'
(Pdb) request.GET.get('selects')
(Pdb) request.GET.get('selects')
'[{"pk":"57226796-0960-428a-88aa-ba4120ad34b4"}]'
```

Comment: I would guess the problem is that `selects` are not sent with every AJAX request. Did you check that in your browser's dev console?

Comment: I have these results within the same ajax request. The data are correctly sends through ajax. I just type the same command again and again in the python console while the execution is paused by  set_trace(). and the console returns the objects only every two times...

Comment: You could have 2 threads on a server side, one of them response right and other is not this may be due to the session, cookies or cache error.

Comment: the ajax call is triggered by a click that is defined in a 'parent' ajax call. One may say it is related... but how ? ajax functions are not calling the same url.

Answer (score 0):

well I finally found it.
the click() event that triggered the ajax call was related to the href attribute of an  element. And as I didn't halt the execution of the function, the link was activated and a call to the django view without parameters was send...
the ajax call with `return false;` or `e.preventDefault();`

I modified the ajax call a little bit :

```
function ajaxActionMenu(pk_list,url){
  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    data:{'pk_list':JSON.stringify(pk_list)},
    url: url,
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
      jQuery.each(data, function(index,value){
        $("#Modal .modal-body .nav").append('<a class="nav-link" href="'+value["url"]+'">'+value["menuitem"]+'</a>');
      });
    },
    complete: function(){
      $("#Modal .modal-body .nav").on("click",".nav-link",function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the activation of the href link
        var urlLink=$(this).attr("href");
        ajaxAction(pk_list,urlLink);
        $("#Modal").modal("show");
      });

    }
  });
}
```